# Can a sharepoint security patch automatically upgrade your sharepoint installation. 

Tags: upgrade, wss-3.0, debugging, 2007

Can a sharepoint security patch automatically upgrade your sharepoint installation.

Recently my company experienced an outage after installing a bunch of Microsoft Security patches and automatic upgrade is currently my best guess ??

These patches included

- [kb2345304](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2345304)
- [kb2345212](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2345212)

Anyway after some investigation it turns out there was mismatch between our

db_schema version 12.0.65 **29.5000**
and our Microsoft.SharePoint.dll    12.0.65 **45.5002**

which was causing issues with checkout of documents and editing properties.

Our test and dev environments are still using version 12.0.6529.5000 for both dll and db_schema. We believed that this was the version of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll we were using in production.

The mystery is how our production environment ended up with version 12.0.6545.5002 of the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.

Any clues on how to investigate this or clues on how it might have happened would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benkaboo,

I just had the exact same thing happen on our WSS 3.0 front end as well and it does appear as though MS10-072 (KB2345304) has updated a number of SharePoint files that are not mentioned in the KB article.

I was actually on the phone w/ Microsoft troubleshooting why I couldn't install a 2nd WFE into our farm and when I told him the SP version he said August 2010 Cumulative was installed.  I know for a fact that we did not install that CU so I went poking around to see what had done it.  Sure enough, after I applied MS10-072, the version of our Microsoft.SharePoint.dll file had gone from 12.0.6535.5003 (MS10-039, KB983444) to 12.0.6545.5002.

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not just going crazy here.